# Languages with number of $a$'s a perfect square

Tags: formal-languages, finite-automata, formal-grammars

Is there any finite automata  ((N/D)FA, NPDA, DPDA, or any variation of a Turring Machine) that can accept the following language:

$\{s \text { is a string over } \{a,b\} \text { such that the number of $a$'s is a perfect square}\}$

Why or why not?

I know it shouldn't belong to a DFA because there are no possible cycles for such a DFA (since the limiting difference between squares is infinite). What about other finite automata? Thanks for any help!

Comment: A Turing machine can compute anything computable, which that language certainly is

Comment: Your language is not context-free. If you intersect it with $a^*$ you get the language of strings of the form $a^{n^2}$, which is unary and not regular, hence is not context-free.